# I need to create an auto-generated email when an item in a Sharepoint list are added which includes few columns from the list item and the attachments

Tags: infopath, microsoft-flow

I'm pretty inexperienced with Sharepoint design, but have taken on the task of creating a basic issue tracker for a project. The idea is when a user find an issue, they will log it into the Sharepoint with all the issue details and screenshots of the issue or error will be attached to it.

I need an email to be sent to some specified people with details of the list item in a tabular format and  attach all the screenshots of the error that is present in the list item.

I know this requires a workflow most likely to achieve, but I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate source of assistance that isn't above my level of understanding.

I have infopath and microsoft flow. Can we do this using any of these.
Hopefully I can find some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we could do that using Microsoft Flow, SharePoint designer workflow or Nintex workflow.

Follow the below steps:

Step1:

[image: Send attachments from a list using MS Flow]

Step2:

[image: Send attachments from a list using MS Flow]
[image: Send attachments from a list using MS Flow]

Below are the good reference articles:

- [Send email with attachment from SharePoint list when condition is met](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Send-email-with-attachment-from-SharePoint-list-when-condition/td-p/351749)
- [Send list Item attachment as email attachment using flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-list-Item-attachment-as-email-attachment-using-flow/td-p/34836)

For HTML column formatting in the Microsoft Flow, refer to the below article:

[Learn HTML table formatting using Microsoft Power Automate step by step](https://global-sharepoint.com/uncategorized/learn-html-table-formatting-using-microsoft-power-automate-step-by-step/)

Comment: Hello Habibur, Thank you so much. The step by step procedure you provided proved very helpful. :) I had a query regarding the table which is to be sent in the mail body. I wanted only the row data that has been added to the sharepoint list. here, as of now, it is sending the whole sharepoint list including the earlier present rows in the sharepoint list. Could you please help me where do I add the condition that it should take only the newly added row. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: Good to know it helped you :-) For current item, you can add the "for selected item"  action, it will give the current item not all list items.. you can refer this link : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-current-List-Item/m-p/253168#M25281

Comment: Thank you, Habibur. This really helped! :)

Comment: Welcome mate, happy to help and share my knowledge :-)

Comment: I had a query. Is it possible to have two attachment fields. I have one attachment field already but I require one more add attachment option to upload an image which will be used in the body of the email.

Comment: Direct way we can not create attachment column in SharePoint.. you can refer this link for some work around... however, for images you can create pictures type column. http://sahadevblogs.blogspot.com/2016/08/solution-for-creating-multiple.html?m=1     I think for new question, it will be better to start a  new question, so that other community members also can have their opinion and answer :-)

Comment: Hello Habibur, Good day..:)  really appreciate all your help. :)
I had a query regarding microsoft flow that I created following your step by step procedure for auto generated email when a new item is created in the list. now, the query is if I upload 3 files to the item out of which 1 is an image file. Can Microsoft flow identify the image file and add it to the mail body? Sorry I am not from a technical background so my questions may seem to be stupid to you.. :)

Comment: Hi Hiranya - Good day :-)  SharePoint attachment field is not restricted with any certain file types, we can attach all allowed file types include image :-), now the way you are reading the attachment column in the Microsoft flow, you will get image file as well (your present MS logic should handle that as it is not bothering about file types, it reads only the attachment columns).  Now, if you want to segregate the image file separately in the email body - then while reading the attachment column, get each file type or extension so that you can identify which one is image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106980/discussion-between-hiranya-and-habibur-rahaman).

Comment: Hi Habibur, thank you for suggesting. :-) is it possible for you to elaborate the steps. Sorry, I am from a non technical background so finding it difficult. :-(

Comment: Sorry, actually I am held up with my work. I have not done this before using flow but it should be handled by Flow... You are getting the attachment by the get attachment action... Then you are applying for each loop the attachment collection... then inside the foreach loop you are reading content of each attachment... once you are here you can read the each individual attachment file type like image or any other... Here whichever image file add those into a new column header in your email body... the way you are doing for other types at present.

Comment: Refer these two examples :
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Get-attachment-content/m-p/95711#M13228


https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Getting-attachments-from-SharePoint-List-and-automatically/m-p/283333#M29437

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Getting-attachments-from-SharePoint-List-and-automatically/m-p/283333#M29437